# populate dropdown list from html

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I found posts for populating from database, classes, xml, etc but I cannot seem to find one for populating a dropdownlist straight from the web page.

```
          <div class="editor-field">                                                              
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Subject, Model.SubjectList)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Subject)
          </div>
```

I just want to add several items to my dropdownlist without using Model.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you are asking here. If you just want to hardcode values in the view you can do something like this:

```
    @Html.DropDownList("", new List<SelectListItem> { 
        new SelectListItem { Text = "Option 1", Value="1"}, 
        new SelectListItem{Text="Option 2", Value="1"}})
```

You could also create the select list in the controller and store it in the ViewBag.